# Having an index error when running my code

Tags: python, indexing, range

I am fairly new to Python and I am writing a program that can convert a seven digit number into a GTIN-8 code with a check digit also. It allows me to run it, but after I enter my number it gives me the error:

```
IndexError: String index out of range
```

My code is as follows:

```
sevenNum = ""
gtinNum = ""
checkDigit = ""
total = ""

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 0

def GTINCalc():
    a = int(sevenNum[0])*3
    b = int(sevenNum[1])*1
    c = int(sevenNum[2])*3
    d = int(sevenNum[3])*1
    e = int(sevenNum[4])*3
    f = int(sevenNum[5])*1
    g = int(sevenNum[6])*3

    total = int(a+b+c+d+e+f+g)

    checkDigit = (total + 9) // 10 * 10 - total

    print("GTIN-8 Code: {0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}".format(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, checkDigit))


def sevenNumAsk():
    sevenNum = input("Enter a 7 digit number to be converted into a GTIN-8 Number")
    if sevenNum.isdigit() == True and len(sevenNum) == 7:
        print("Valid Number - Calculating GTIN-8...")
        GTINCalc()
    else:
        print("The number is not valid - please re-enter ")
        sevenNumAsk()

sevenNumAsk()
```

The part that is highlighted is:

```
a = int(sevenNum[0])*3
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on indentation etc. of this questions code, sevenNum may not be a global variable like you expect. As a side note, try passing the variables through arguments (which is better practice too, in general)

Comment: @ScottStainton Alex Hall has given me a good fix for it. I see what you mean about no index. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

`sevenNum` is a local variable inside `sevenNumAsk` and doesn't affect the global variable you created at the top. Do this:

```
def sevenNumAsk():
    global sevenNum
    sevenNum = ...
```

and it will act as you expect. Better yet, use a class or pass `sevenNum` as a parameter. Global variables are generally bad and this is one of the reasons why.

Comment: I have already declared sevenNum at the top of the code. I will try to amend it and see what will happen.

Comment: Works, much appreciated!

Comment: you declared it at the top, but the function didn't know to use the global definition (hence the `global` modifier)